# MacroError: The macro you imported from "undefined" is being executed outside the context of compilation with babel-plugin-macros

Tags: node.js, macros

I'm getting this error in a project for a node script. How can I resolve this issue? I don't understand why it considers my script a macro also..?

> MacroError: The macro you imported from "undefined" is being executed
> outside the context of compilation with babel-plugin-macros. This
> indicates that you don't have the babel plugin "babel-plugin-macros"
> configured correctly. Please see the documentation for how to
> configure babel-plugin-macros properly:
> https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros/blob/master/other/docs/user.md

I have tried following the url and adding this to my .babelrc and it doesn't solve the problem.

```
{
  "plugins": ["macros"]
}
```